# Hazelcast Management Centre frequently gets down

Tags: tomcat7, hazelcast

I have three node cluster of Hazelcast version 3.7.5 deployed in Windows and deployed the mancenter-3.7.5 in tomcat server(7.0.70) as Windows Service.

The mancenter service is getting frequently down. On monitoring the tomcat server it is found that the heap consumption is increasing gradually which never falls down. GC is happening intermittently but the heap consumption grows very fast which suspends the application completely.

This happens when the data is flowing into map with heavy traffic.

Anyone have idea of like suggested Tomcat version for 3.7.5 of mancenter and also the jvm options. Any quick answer is very helpful.

Comment: You can check http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#suggested-heap-size for the suggested heap size for Management Center. Approximately how much time does it take for it to go down?

Comment: How much have you allocated the heap side right now and how many Distributed data structures are you using?

Comment: For this settings -Xms=256m -Xmx=2048m it holds for one hour. if we restart tomcat it works well and goes down after one hour under traffic. If there is no traffic everything goes well.

Comment: Right now we have 10 maps created but the continuous message flow will be in 4 maps.

Comment: Any suggestion in tomcat version.

Comment: @RajiNatarajan Tomcat version should not make any difference, but more recent versions would be better as it might be due to a bug in your Tomcat version. If you can verify that it happens with different Tomcat versions, you can create an issue [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new) - hopefully along with the exact steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @emre Created an issue with the steps to reproduce the issue.[Issuelink](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10141) for your reference .